# Bootstrap 3 Collapsible Navbar Text and Links Not Aligning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm having trouble keeping text tagged with `class="navbar-text"` in line with other links in the navbar. Building off of the [Bootstrap 3 example for a fixed top navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/), I noticed that any time the browser width is <768 pixels, the collapsible menu items shows the text without the proper spacing and butted up against the first link in the menu:

[image: Misaligned navbar]

(http://www.bootply.com/98784)

The text "Business Infrastructure Services" is a `<p>` tagged with `class="navbar-text"` as recommended for [text strings in navbars](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-text). It looks fine when it is not collapsed (browser width >768 pixels). And, when I try to tag the text as an `<a>`, the styling is fine and everything looks good. But, it's not meant to be a link, but rather a simple string of text. I've also tried moving the `<p>` out of the `<ul>`, but it still shows up weird. Any suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit 12/5/13:** I apologize if I was unclear in what I was trying to achieve. Basically, I'd like the `<p class="navbar-text">` to appear on its own line, just like the other links in the `<ul>`, like this:

[image: How the navbar should look]

**Edit 12/6/13:** Since the release of Bootstrap v. 3.0.3, this issue is partially resolved. The text string now appears on its own line, but doesn't have the proper indentation (See https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11735):

[image: Text on its own line, but not indented properly]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure why you're having trouble with Bootstrap's layout, but you just need to get the two types of elements' styles synchronized at mobile sizes:

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/26g5ezok/)**

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {    
    p.navbar-text {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px 15px;
    }
    .navbar li {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}
```

---

Update: The original fiddles were lost, so I've attempted to recreate them. In response to the OP's comment about Bootstrap v3.0.3, the overflow statement can be eliminated.

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/26g5ezok/6/)**

Comment: Thanks! You nailed it. I wonder if that's something that ought to be integrated into Bootstrap. Thoughts?

Comment: I suspect that something about how you're implementing it is causing the issue--not that there's a bug or omission in Bootstrap.

Comment: see the edit above. It looks like with the release of v. 3.0.3 just recently, the issue is partially resolved; however, there is still an indentation problem. (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11735)